# How to compare a string to a date in postman test?

Tags: javascript, testing, postman, functional-testing

Suppose a API request fetches a users id, email address and birthday. Sample API Request below:

```
GET: /v1/users HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: bearer {access_token}
```

For the above request, the following is the response:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "random@random.com",
            "birthday": "1990-01-01"
        },
        {
            "id": 40,
            "email": "random1@random1.com",
            "birthday": "1990-18-10"
        }
],
    "last": false,
    "total_elements": 2,
    "total_pages": 1,
    "sort": null,
    "first": true,
    "number_of_elements": 2,
    "size": 20,
    "number": 0
}
```

Now, what will be the test in postman to make sure that all the returned values under birthday node is greater than 1988-18-01?

I have tried the following:

```
pm.test("Check birthday greater than 1988-18-01", () => {
    for (i = 0; i < jsonData.content.length; i++) {
        var a = '1988-18-01'; 
        pm.expect(jsonData.content[i].birthday).to.be.above(a);
    }
});
```

But postman says: "Check birthday greater than 1988-18-01 | AssertionError: expected '1990-01-01' to be a number or a date".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So firstly, the dates need to be converted to a format that JS accepts and use the Date constructor to generate the complete date.

Next, the 'above' function in **pm** accepts an integer, so the date format will not be compared.
To fix this, we can convert the date to integer format by using the **.getTime()** function.

Lastly, it's not a good practice to declare variables inside a for loop.
Here's what you can replace your test with:

```
pm.test("Check birthday greater than 1988-18-01", () => {

   let date, 
   isoFormatDate,
   a = new Date('1988-01-18').getTime();

   for (i = 0; i < jsonData.content.length; i++) {
    
      date = jsonData.content[i].birthday;
            
      isoFormatDate = new Date(date).getTime(); // Converting to integer from date format
    
      pm.expect(isoFormatDate).to.be.above(a);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Sivcan! 
However, it still fails. Now postman says: "Check birthday greater than 1988-18-01 | AssertionError: expected NaN to be above 569462400000"

Comment: Are you sure all your dates are correct in the response ?
Can you share the date where it's failing.
Just console.log the date and check in Postman Console.

Comment: @NoorYeaserKhan - The date format should be : YYYY-DD-MM

Comment: Sorry Sivcan! But the API is returning date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Ok - The tests passes when I commented out the swapping line from the code that you've provided. So the final code is same as above except the following line: [date[1], date[2]] = [date[2], date[1]]; // swapping.

As per information provided here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp
It seems like ISO Date format is YYYY-MM-DD.

Thanks a bunch for your help and also the quick responses!

Comment: Sivcan - can you please update your solution without the swapping line?

Comment: You're welcome, but the example you posted had the date as "birthday": "1990-18-10" viz of the format YYYY-DD-MM that's why I was breaking the date and swapping the month and date. 
Anyway, So I'll remove those lines also.